# Examples of top academics who weren't prodigies

Tags: professorship, academic-history

I'm looking for examples of people who are at the very top of their fields who weren't child prodigies, and followed quite a "normal" path in life (high school > college > grad school) before finding their passion in a field and then becoming a top academic at a top institution at it. We come across people like Terry Tao who had some sort of divine gift to do mathematics and was very much a child prodigy (he could do high school mathematics at the age of 8-9 and won an Olympiad gold medal at the age of 13), but I'm looking for people who achieved as much success as Tao (even a little less is fine considering that Tao is often regarded as the "best mathematician in the world", but I'm looking for someone in the same tier) without being child prodigies, or knowing what their passion was right from childhood. Examples?

Comment: Would Albert Einstein count?

Comment: @nick012000 just about to say him as well - flunked school then wow...

Comment: Einstein might not be a great example. From Wikipedia: "A family tutor Max Talmud says that after he had given the 12-year-old Einstein a geometry textbook, after a short time '[Einstein] had worked through the whole book. He thereupon devoted himself to higher mathematics... Soon the flight of his mathematical genius was so high I could not follow.' ... Einstein started teaching himself calculus at 12, and as a 14-year-old he says he had 'mastered integral and differential calculus'."

Comment: Maybe Smale: "Smale...entered the University of Michigan in 1948. Initially, he was a good student, placing into an honors calculus sequence... and earning himself As. However, his sophomore and junior years were marred with mediocre grades, mostly Bs, Cs and even an F in nuclear physics. However, with some luck, Smale was accepted as a graduate student at the U. of Michigan's mathematics department. Yet again, Smale performed poorly in his first years, earning a C average as a graduate student. It was only when the department chair threatened to kick Smale out that he began to work hard."

Comment: Wouldn't this be virtually everyone? Most Nobel Laureates, for example, are not child prodigies.

Comment: How do we get rid of phony rumors like "Einstein flunked school"?  Only by challenging them every time they come up.

Comment: @GEdgar  perhaps you need to become the editor for several books and write the next edition...

Comment: Note that one of the problems with finding the truth is that people create, inflate, and misremember the greatness of people in retrospect. "Oh yes, even as a baby he was brilliant" is a popular and normal parenting observation, but the stories don't get preserved through decades of the person doesn't accomplish anything. "They always seemed like a moron to me, but then they did great things so I guess I was wrong about them" is a story most people don't want to tell, even when true. Temple Grandin is one of the rare exceptions, as autism was thought to prevent any such intellectual ability.

Comment: Him not being an academic, although an intellectual, I like Orson Welles' quote: "I started at the top and worked my way to the bottom." - doesn't quite answer the question but puts a different slant on it...

Comment: I agree with Allure there are simply too many to count. Especially in the core sciences like chemistry and biology where you can' t do much without the right equipment even if you are a child prodigy.

Comment: There's a major sample bias issue here.  A former prodigy is frequently identified as such; if you were never a prodigy, probably no one has ever felt the need to point this out about you.

Comment: Following up on Allure's comment, I just skimmed the Wikipedia pages on all the 2018 Nobel laureates, and there's no evidence that any of them were prodigies.

Comment: I thought Fresnel might have been, but he also showed signs of early talent. Perhaps the best example is Charles Darwin, who was, to my knowledge, considered unremarkable until his famous trip.

Comment: Kind of a chicken and egg problem. People who are lucky enough to have family environments that support early achievement are vastly more likely to later get opportunities that enable adult achievement.

Answer (score 4):

[Thomas Kuhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Kuhn) literally switched fields after completing his PhD in physics and is a modern philosopher well known for his work in the philosophy of science, particularly for his book [The Structure of Scientific Revolutions](http://The%20Structure%20of%20Scientific%20Revolutions)

[Karl Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Pearson), may be another example. Although he initially studied mathematics and then physics, he proceeded onto other things like law before eventually switching back to mathematics and making his big contributions (like establishing mathematical statistics). I have not been able to find anything immediately obvious to indicate he was a child prodigy.

As an ecologist, I'd hazard to guess that most famous ecologists were never child prodigies, but they almost certainly identified their passions early on in life while playing outside as children, which violates the

> before finding their passion in a field

part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind that "prodigies" are much more common in STEM fields, especially math and physics, than in other fields. Thus, one answer to this question is simply to point to any prominent individual outside STEM.

But even inside math and science, there are a lot of examples. For example, Steven Chu, who received the Nobel Prize in Physics, has talked about how he didn't really excel as a student until his undergraduate years. See [his short autobiographical summary here](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1997/chu/biographical/).

Also your standard from your question is Terry Tao, then almost any mathematician who is as prominent as Tao is less of a prodigy. This raises a question of what one means by a prodigy? For example, does doing very well at the IMO count? But that's actually designed for the highest performing high school students. One example here that's relevant is Peter Scholze, who did very well in the IMO, and like Tao is a Fields Medalist. But my understanding is that while he was a very strong student when he was young, calling him a prodigy would have been a stretch, especially if your standard is Tao. So, where you draw the lines here will matter.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first paragraph. It may just be true that they are easier to _recognize_ in STEM fields. A lot of people seem awed by any mathematical ability, for example.

Comment: @Buffy That's a valid point. One issue is what would it mean? In STEM fields (and music) it is clear. But for example, what would it mean for someone to be a prodigy in history or anthropology? I know someone who at the age of about 10 was reading professional biographies of major historical figures, but I don't think anyone labeled him a prodigy, while if he had been doing calculus at that age, people would. So maybe part of this is as you note that people are awed by math ability in general.

Comment: Skill in music are also recurrent. Quite an academical environment as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Hugh Herr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Herr) is a remarkable individual and leading academic whose original career  had basically nothing to do with academia: he was a rock climber.

After becoming a double amputee in an accident, however, he went back to school and rose to prominence in prosthetics.  He has been a key figure in revolutionizing the field, and you know his work, even if you don't know his name.

His passion is clear and well-defined and indisputably shaped by his accident.